# How to highlight multiple lines?

Tags: highlight

When review code, it would be convenient if we can highlight multiple lines at the same time, instead of only current cursor line is highlighted.

`:set cursorline` only highlight current line.
`:nnoremap <silent> <Leader>l ml:execute 'match Search /\%'.line('.').'l/'<CR>` can only highlight one extra line.

Want to keep all marked lines highlighted.

Comment: You question is a bit too broad so far: are you talking about `cursorline` or some syntax highlighting? And on which criterion would you like to highlight your lines?

Comment: Requirement is simple: move cursor to line a, highlight current line; move cursor to another line b, highlight it, ..., keep all marked lines highlighted. It doesn't need syntax highlighting. `cursorline` can only highlight current line.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to keep some lines highlighted while doing something else than visual selection. One possible solution would be to add these two lines to your `.vimrc`: `syntax region CoreReview start=/"CR/ end=/"RC/` and `highlight CoreReview ctermbg=LightGreen`. You can then put `"CR` at the beginning of the code you are reviewing and `"RC` at the end to highlight the background. It is even possible to create a mapping which will add the markers for you when you are in visual selection and remove them when you don't need them anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mention in your question, the `:match` command only allows a single match to be set up. For multiple matches, you can use the `matchadd()` function. You can adapt your existing mapping to use this like so:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <Leader>l :call matchadd('Search', '\%'.line('.').'l')<CR>
```

For your expressed purpose of reviewing code, this should be sufficient. However, if you are adding/removing lines above the lines you have marked, this might not work as you desire: the marks will not move with the lines. There are ways around this, but all will result in much more complicated code.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for below answer, find a way to highlight multiple lines.
https://superuser.com/a/697070/366981

Install plugin:[multiselect-2.2.zip](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=953).
`Ctrl and left click` to select and highlight any line.
`Ctrl and left click` again to remove highlight.
`<leader>msc`to clear all selection.

[image]

Another method: [Highlight multiple words](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50984553/3760602)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This answer may be a couple years late but since I just had the same question, and none of these answers were even close to being helpful I though I'd share my solution.

I was wanting to improve my mapping that is similar to OP's that highlights a single line :

```
nnoremap <leader>l :call matchadd('LineHighlight', '\%'.line('.').'l')<cr>
```

to be able to visually select multiple lines and highlight all of them.

After being unsuccessful trying to simply modify the mapping to a `vnnoremap` that takes a range I wrote a function that will run a loop for each line in the selection.

```
highlight LineHighlight ctermbg=100 guibg=#374090
vnoremap <leader>l :<c-u>call HiglightVisualLines()
nnoremap <leader>c :call clearmatches()

" HiglightVisualLines()
" loop throough visually selected lines and give them highlighting
function! HiglightVisualLines()
    for i in range(line('v'),line("'>"))
        call matchadd('LineHighlight', '\%'.i.'l')
    endfor
endfunction
```

As Rich mentioned with his comment, the highlighting is based on line number, not the content of the line, so adding lines above the highlighting will 'break' it.

Answer (score -1):

You press capital V and j or k to select other lines.

Comment: This only select continuous lines?

Comment: I can see why you'd think the OP wants what you think. But you're wrong. You should remove your answer from here.